# Regular Expression for strong password in MVC model

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, model, passwords

I need to create a regular expression to validate a strong password in my MVC Model.  Here are the rules that I need to apply:

- Min 7 characters
- Max 15 characters
- At least 3 out of 4 different types of characters.

  - Numbers
  - Lowercase
  - Uppercase
  - Special (viz. `!@#$%&/=?_.`)

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[RegularExpression("([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[\\W]){4}[a-zA-Z0-9\\W]{3,11}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid password format")]        
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain whats not working

Comment: Sorry, new here :) Added.

Comment: Suggest your look at some of the examples [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Thanks , will take a look

Comment: What are the *special characters*? A specific set or any UNICODE-character not belonging to any of the other groups?

Comment: special characters : !@#$%&/=?_.-

Comment: Max 15 is a bad idea. It's too short for people that want to use strong random passwords from password managers. Go for max 72 at least

Answer (score 4):

Creating a regex that will find any number of different kinds of character classes in any order is a little challenging because as soon as you match a character, it's already captured and you can't back it up.  However, the .NET regex engine supports lookahead expressions.  Therefore, you can check to make sure that a string contains something without actually capturing any of the string.  For instance, let's say that you want to find any 10 character long string that contains at least one instance of the letter "J".  You could do that easily with a lookahead expression, like this:

```
(?=.*J).{10}
```

The `(?=)` construct declares a lookahead pattern.  The pattern it looks for is `.*J`, which means that, starting at the current position, there can be any number of any character followed by a letter "J".  If anything comes after the J, that's fine, it will still match.  However, since it's a lookahead, none of those characters were actually captured, so then the `.{10}` capturing part of the pattern picks up from the original position and matches from there.  Since the lookaheads don't move the position at all, you can put multiple of them in a row without consequence, so you can do something like this:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W).{7,15}$
```

As far as applying only three of the four character class rules, the only way I can think of to do that would be to list all of the combinations (e.g. for two of the three rules A, B, and C, you could match AB|AC|BC) .  So for instance, if you were only concerned with two of the three (uppercase, lowercase, and digits, for instance), you could structure your lookaheads like this:

```
(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]))
```

Making it support there out of four would just be a matter of making the list of options even longer...

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly i was looking for !

Comment: And you can also mention the contrast principle that can be illustrated with `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\w*\W).{7,15}$`

Comment: @stribizhev Very [interesting](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).  I've done patterns like that both ways but never realized there was any sort of efficiency difference.  Good to know.  You learn something new every day.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't see how this takes into account that only three of the types is needed. As I see it, with this regex all four need to be present, or...?

Comment: @ClasG, That's a really good point :)  I just noticed that myself too as I was editing the question's formatting.

Comment: @ClasG See my updated answer.  I don't suppose you have a suggestion for a more elegant solution?  If so, I'd be very curious to hear it.

Comment: @StevenDoggart See my answer (and comment to that).

Comment: @StevenDoggart what about escape sequence error, we face when using this regex in .NET?

Comment: @MHanif Many languages, like C#, use the backslash character as the escape character.  For instance,, `\n` in a string is interpreted as a line feed rather than those literal characters.  So, when you need to put an actual backslash in a string literal, you have to use an escape sequence.  For instance, in C#, if you want to put the regex pattern `.*\d` in a string literal, you would have to double the backslash (e.g. `var pattern = ".*\\d";`).

Comment: Since regex patterns often contain a lot of backslashes, doubling them all can get confusing.  Therefore regex patterns are often written in C# using a verbatim string literal (one that starts with the `@` symbol).  Verbatim string literals don't use the backslash character as an escape character.  So, you can instead simply say `var pattern = @".*\d";`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I get my code working with the latter one, The Regex solution you provided worked perfectly fine for my scenario

Answer (score 2):

A development of Steven's answer would be to test for all possible combinations of the *types*:

```
^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])).{7,15}$
```

Also using the given *special characters*.

In a more readable form

```
^((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])|
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%&\/=?_.-])).{7,15}$
```

Test for either of the possible four combinations of *types* and make sure there are 7-14 of them.

Regards

Comment: I'm leaving this answer here because it has the full regex as I see it, but Steven cracked the code and should have the credit.